# Get data from two data source and run in one loop in php

Tags: php

This is kind of silly question. I have a requirement to get data from two data sources (one Oracle and another SQL Server) and compare the data. If the both data same print but if one data missing print only one side leave other blank. Currently I run two while loops and put in side by side in a table. But data not identical some times. I tried one while loop inside another but results not same as expected. How can I archive this? Is there anyway I can access data inside a one loop?

For example :
Source 1 - [2018-10-15,2018-10-16,2018-10-18,2018-10-19]
Source 2 - [2018-10-15,2018-10-18]

Table Expected :

### Source 1 | Source 2

2018-10-15  | 2018-10-15
2018-10-16  | No Data
2018-10-18  | 2018-10-18
2018-10-19  | No Data

```
$contents .= '<div class="table-responsive col-md-6"><table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr class="table-active"><th>Time Detail 1</th></tr></thead>';   

while (odbc_fetch_row($result_1)){
    $F_time = odbc_result($result_1,"Time1");
    $s_id = odbc_result($result_1,"id");
    $contents .= '<tr><td class="col-md-1">' . $F_time . ' <sup class="badge badge-success"> ' . $s_id . '</sup></td></tr>';
}

$contents .= '</table></div><div class="table-responsive col-md-6"><table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr class="table-active"><th>Time Detail 2</th></tr></thead>';

while (odbc_fetch_row($$result_2)){
    $F_time2 = odbc_result($$result_2,"time2");
    $contents .= '<tr><td class="col-md-1">' . $F_time2 . '</td></tr>';
}

$contents .= '</table></div></div>';
```

Comment: It's not clear what "missing" means in this case. Can you provide a small example dataset, say 3-5 rows of what might be in each database, which would make this clearer?

Comment: For example :   
Source 1 - [2018-10-15,2018-10-16,2018-10-18,2018-10-19]  
Source 2 - [2018-10-15,2018-10-18]  

Table Expected :  
  
Source 1 | Source 2  
--------------------------  
2018-10-15  | 2018-10-15  
2018-10-16  | No Data  
2018-10-18  | 2018-10-18  
2018-10-19  | No Data

Comment: I have added it to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get have array then try this

```
    $array = array('2018-10-15','2018-10-16','2018-10-18','2018-10-19');
    $array1 = array('2018-10-15','2018-10-18');

    $result=array_unique(array_merge($array,$array1));
    $fristarray = $secondarray = array();
    foreach ($result as $value) {   
        if(in_array($value, $array)){
            $fristarray[] = $value;
        }else{
            $fristarray[] = 'No Data';
        }
        if(in_array($value, $array1)){
            $secondarray[] = $value;
        }else{
            $secondarray[] = 'No Data';
        }       
    }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($fristarray);
echo '</pre>';


echo '<pre>';
print_r($secondarray);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Ouput like**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-10-15
    [1] => 2018-10-16
    [2] => 2018-10-18
    [3] => 2018-10-19
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-10-15
    [1] => No Data
    [2] => 2018-10-18
    [3] => No Data
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have data that's usually the same, use whatever the unique data is that should match (ideally some sort of ID) as a key for comparison.

1. Retrieve your data from both data sources separately. Create separate arrays for them, where the keys are the data from the field you're comparing between data sources, and the values are the full record.
2. Merge the keys of those two arrays into a new array, and (optionally) sort that array.
3. Iterate over the merged keys array, creating a row for each key. For each data source, if there's data present, render it normally in a cell; otherwise render an empty cell.

This will get you a table with all elements from both data sources, with empty cells where one source had the data but the other didn't.

Comment: Thanks. I already have separate arrays and the part i'm struggling with is how to merge and compare. It would be great if you can give me an example.

Comment: Sorry, that's a lot of code to write for an SO question; this approach should work, but you will need to do the legwork yourself.